# Can we use 'one' after uncountable nouns?

Tags: grammar, uncountable-nouns

For example, is it possible to say the following:

> `'Music degraded from a very good one to a bad one'`

If not, what's the natural way to say it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, "one" is always something countable.

A natural way to say this would be, "The music degraded from very good to bad."